# Best way to keep the label vertically aligned in a form?

Tags: html, css

I need my form to have label and input boxes vertically center aligned. I need to handle the scenario where the label goes to multiple line (because of fixed width) and scenario where textarea causes label to be top aligned.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas014/gusfbyed/1/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="label"><label>label one</label></div>
  <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="one" /></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
.input {
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.row{ padding: 3px 0; }
.clear{ clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inline block instead of float.

```
.label, .input {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

<kbd>[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gusfbyed/5/)</kbd>

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.row {
    padding: 3px 0;
}
.label, .input {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.label {
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.input {
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label one</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="one" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label two large</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="two" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label three very large</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="three" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label four that is longer than thought</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="four" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label textarea</label></div>
    <div class="input"><textarea placeholder="Large text area"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Or use CSS table layout.

```
.row {
    display: table;
}
.label, .input {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

<kbd>**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gusfbyed/6/)**</kbd>

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.row {
    display: table;
    padding: 3px 0;
}
.label, .input {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.label {
    width: 100px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.input {
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label one</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="one" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label two large</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="two" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label three very large</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="three" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label four that is longer than thought</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" placeholder="four" /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="label"><label>label textarea</label></div>
    <div class="input"><textarea placeholder="Large text area"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Either way, No need clear floats.

Comment: I like the inline-block option. Don't have to worry about clearing the floats either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try, putting the line-height on the label the same as the height on the input

```
label {
    line-height: 19px;
}
```

or just add some padding-top on the label,

```
label {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Line height will affect the labels that come in multiple lines adversely. And I can't add fixed padding, that will create alignment issues with multiple line label and textarea etc.